# Why is the preventDefault() method not working for me in my react application?

Tags: reactjs

I used a form to capture input from user. But once the user clicks on the submit button, the page reloads. I don't want it to reload. That was why I decided to use preventDefault() method.
How can I get this to work?

```
const handleHeaderValueUpdate = async ( headerId, e) =>{
e.preventDefault()
console.log(headerId)

  setUpdating(true)
  const updatedHeaderValue = {
  username: user.username,
  websiteName,
  sitesubName,
  };
  if(file){                    //logic behind uploading image and the image name
    const data = new FormData();
    const filename = Date.now() + file.name;
    data.append("name", filename);
    data.append("file", file);
    updatedHeaderValue.headerImg = filename;

  
    try{
    await axios.post("/upload", data)//handles the uploading of the image
    //setUpdated(true)
    }catch(err){
        dispatch({type: "UPDATE_FAILURE"})
    }
    }

    try{
    
    await axios.put("/headervalue/" + headerId, updatedHeaderValue)  
     setUpdating(false);
     setTextUpdate(true)
     //setUpdated(true)
  


 }catch(err){
   console.log(err)
}

}
```

Here is part of the form:

```
 <form onSubmit={()=>handleHeaderValueUpdate(headerId)} className="dashboard-form">

        <div className='dasboard-input-div'>
          <p className="dashboard-label">Website Name</p>
          {dashboardEditMode ? <input className="dashboard-input" type="text" placeholder={singleValues.websiteName} autoFocus
             onChange={(e) => setWebsiteName(e.target.value)}
             required
            /> : 
            <input className="dashboard-input" type="text" placeholder= {singleValues.websiteName} readOnly/>
          }
  </form>
```

Here is the submit button

```
{dashboardEditMode && <button className={updating ? "updateModeBTN-unclick updateModeBTN" : "updateModeBTN"} type="submit">Update</button>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you do not send the event to the `handleHeaderValueUpdate` function. You should change:

```
<form onSubmit={()=>handleHeaderValueUpdate(headerId)}
```

to:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => handleHeaderValueUpdate(headerId, e)}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-robinson-x6yjk?file=/src/App.js:250-304) for a live working example.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. Was wondering why it is like that.. because I have another similar line of codes that worked without adding the event inside the form. This is the sample code here: <form className={updated ? "settingsform2 settingsform" : "settingsform"} onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
                    <label>Profile Picture</label>  <button className={isFetching ? "settingsSubmit2 settingsSubmit": updated ? "settingsSubmit2 settingsSubmit": "settingsSubmit"} type="submit">
                        Update</button> </form>

Comment: I am still learning, that is why I always would like to know why something worked differently. Could it be because the button is embedded within the form? Thank you once again.

Comment: Because, the first arg of `onsubmit` is the event. This usage defines a new arrow function here. If you say `onSubmit={handleUpdate}` you can handle submit directly in your component like `handleUpdate(e)`. But you cannot handle it the same way if you say `onSubmit={() =>handleUpdate()}`. Then you should send the event manually like `onSubmit={(e) =>handleUpdate(e)}`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get the point now and I have learnt this. I am grateful.